# Building libcurl with nss support

Tags: libcurl, nss

I built the 64-bit version of nss and am trying to use it to build the curl library using the --without-ssl and --with-nss=NSS_ROOT option.

During the configure stage, I see the following:

```
checking for PK11_CreateGenericObject in -lnss3... no
checking for NSS_Initialize in -lnss3... no
checking for ssl_version in -laxtls... no
configure: WARNING: SSL disabled, you will not be able to use HTTPS, FTPS, NTLM and more.
configure: WARNING: Use --with-ssl, --with-gnutls, --with-polarssl, --with-cyassl, --with-nss or --with-axtls to address this.
```

and finally libcurl is build without https support.

```
  curl version:     7.25.0
  Host setup:       x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Install prefix:   /usr/local
  Compiler:         gcc
  SSL support:      no      (--with-{ssl,gnutls,nss,polarssl,cyassl,axtls} )
  SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
  zlib support:     enabled
  krb4 support:     no      (--with-krb4*)
  GSSAPI support:   no      (--with-gssapi)
  SPNEGO support:   no      (--with-spnego)
  TLS-SRP support:  no      (--enable-tls-srp)
  resolver:         default (--enable-ares / --enable-threaded-resolver)
  ipv6 support:     no      (--enable-ipv6)
  IDN support:      no      (--with-libidn)
  Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  enabled
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   no
  ca cert path:     no
  LDAP support:     enabled (OpenLDAP)
  LDAPS support:    enabled
  RTSP support:     enabled
  RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP GOPHER HTTP IMAP LDAP LDAPS POP3 RTSP SMTP TELNET TFTP
```

Can somebody tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to

```
nss-3.12.6/mozilla/dist/Linux2.6_x86_64_glibc_PTH_64_DBG.OBJ/lib
```

to make it work.

Thanks,
Raj